# let : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $x_n=\sqrt{1+(1+1/n)^2}+\sqrt{1+(1-1/n)^2}$ then : $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{20}}\dfrac{1}{x_i}=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $x_n=\sqrt{1+(1+1/n)^2}+\sqrt{1+(1-1/n)^2}$

then :

$$\sum_{i=1}^{20}\dfrac{1}{x_i}=?$$

---

my try :

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{13}}+...$$

But boring .

Comment: You get bored very quickly. In two terms, how can you even tell if there's a helpful pattern?

Comment: Are we supposed to believe that $$\frac1{x_1}=\frac1{\sqrt5}\ ?$$ Boring...

Answer (score 5):

Let me try.

$$\frac{1}{x_n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(1+1/n)^2}+\sqrt{1+(1-1/n)^2}}$$

$$= \frac{\sqrt{1+(1+1/n)^2}-\sqrt{1+(1-1/n)^2}}{\frac{4}{n}}$$
$$= \frac{1}{4}\left(\sqrt{n^2+(n+1)^2}-\sqrt{n^2+(n-1)^2}\right)$$

Then, $$\sum_{i=1}^{20}\frac{1}{x_i} = \frac{1}{4}\left(\sqrt{20^2+21^2}-\sqrt{1^2+0^2}\right) = 7.$$

Answer (score 1):

I notice that:

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(1+1/n)^2}+\sqrt{1+(1-1/n)^2}} &= \frac{\sqrt{1+(1+1/n)^2}-\sqrt{1+(1-1/n)^2}}{(1+(1+1/n)^2)-(1+(1-1/n)^2)}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{1+(1+1/n)^2}-\sqrt{1+(1-1/n)^2}}{(1+1/n)^2-(1-1/n)^2}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{1+(1+1/n)^2}-\sqrt{1+(1-1/n)^2}}{4/n}\\
&= \frac14\left(n\sqrt{1+(1+1/n)^2}-n\sqrt{1+(1-1/n)^2}\right)\\
&= \frac14\left(\sqrt{n^2+(n+1)^2}-\sqrt{n^2+(n-1)^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

That last expression provides for a telescoping sum:

$$\frac14\left(\left(\sqrt{1^2+2^2} - \sqrt{1^2+0^2}\right) + \left(\sqrt{2^2+3^2} - \sqrt{2^2+1^2}\right) + \cdots + \left(\sqrt{19^2+20^2} -
 \sqrt{19^2+18^2}\right) + \left(\sqrt{20^2+21^2} -
 \sqrt{20^2+19^2}\right)\right)$$

which collapses down to:

$$\frac14\left(\sqrt{20^2+21^2} - \sqrt{1^2+0^2}\right)$$

Comment: @G T  will look at it later ...and do the calculation again..

Comment: The first term: $\frac{1}{\sqrt5+1}=\frac{\sqrt5-1}{5-1}$. Et cetera.